# partially mocking static with PowerMockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

All the examples I find with partially mocking statics at the end use EasyMock, tehrefore PowerMock.
Is there a way to partially mock statics with mockito - PowerMockito?

Thank you!
Roxana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can partially mock statics using PowerMockito.  The info page for it shows the steps needed.You can find that [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial).  Use the ability to mock the static calls like you need, and you can always use `spy`.  You can also see an example in their documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13).